# JAVA Memory Management | jvm | command to find memory

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

Need few clarity on below questions please .
1.How to check on production server how much is the total memory allocated to your JAVA application.

2.How much memory is occupied by your java application among total memory.

3.what is the command we can use to check the memory available in linux/unix system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, 'top' will show you memory used by running processes and 'free' shows you total and free memory. Check out the man pages for options and how to use.